# Bug in the last loop of operations on a queue

Tags: c++, debugging, queue

This is my solution for this problem statement:
http://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=onlinejudge&page=show_problem&problem=1842

I get a run time error, though the program gives correct output when I used the debugging statement below.

```
while(!q.empty()){
        cn=0;
        while(q.front().first<=ct && cn <=n && q.front().second==cpos){
            allCarT.push_back(ct+t);
            for(i=0; i< sz(allCarT); i++) cout << allCarT[i] << "\n"; //debugging statement give correct answers
            q.pop(); //error occurs here in the last loop
            cn++;
        }

        if(cn==0 && q.front().first > ct){
            ct = q.front().first;
        }else{
            ct+=t;
            if(cpos=="left") cpos="right";
            else cpos="left";
        }
    }
```

Full solution here :https://ideone.com/BCU3UT

Comment: have you tried running this on clang/gcc on your personal pc. You might get extra hints.Ideone says an error about time limit. are you being stuck inside a loop?

Comment: You should provide the problem description in your post, so people don't have to go to an external site to find it. Also, since you get run time error, you should describe the error in your post, so people don't have to guess what the error is.

Comment: [OT]: Note that your algo fails when cars arrive alternatively *faster* that the ferry traversal time.

Comment: Also, do you know for which **input** your program generates a runtime error that you want to fix? If yes, please post it (this is very important). If not, please mention this. In this case, in order to make the guesswork easier for people: you mention that "the program gives correct output", I guess, for some simple input. What is that input? What is the correct output for that input?

Comment: Thanks, anatolyg .. I'll take care of this next time

Comment: all the input gives run time error... I get correct output when I used the debugging statement but the program then crash

Answer (score 0):

In that code, you don't check that queue is empty:

```
while(q.front().first<=ct && cn <=n && q.front().second==cpos){
    allCarT.push_back(ct+t);
    q.pop(); //error occurs here in the last loop
    // queue can be empty now, so you have out of bound access with q.front()
    cn++;
}
```

Comment: Very thank you .. you got it right , really appreciate your help :)